# MongoDB: unknown operator $and

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, operator-keyword

I am working with pymongo. 
I want to return the field *_id* for all the tuples that have the field status different from *0* and different from *1*.

```
return [entry['_id'] for entry in mytable.find(
            {'status':
              {'$and': [
                  {'$ne': 0},
                  {'$ne': 1},
                ]
              }
            }
        )]
```

The following query returns the error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: unknown operator: $and
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

more help : [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)

```
mytable.find(
  {'$and':
       [{'status':  {'$ne': 0 }},
        {'status': {'$ne': 1 }}]
  })
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining why the OP's way is not allowed?